# Does COM provide methods to delay shutdown until all RPCs are done?

Tags: com, rpc, lifecycle, shutdown

I have two processes: a Client and a Server. Client makes a call that the Server starts processing, but the Server can start shutting down before the call is finished. This can cause objects required by the call to suddenly become destroyed, leading to a crash.

The Client and Server communicate through COM. Something that tells the amount of currently active RPCs from and to a given Server process would be extremely helpful in this case.

Does COM, as the layer of communication between these two processes, provide any aid in delaying shutdown when there is active interaction them?

Comment: It is a nonsensical question, a server is only allowed to shutdown after the last Release() call on the last interface pointer it handed out.  Ignoring this requirement, or getting the reference counting wrong, is of course going to bomb the client code.  It is automatic in ATL, review the docs for CoAddRefServerProcess() if you do it yourself.

Comment: The Client talks to the Server via a proxy, which is a COM object. This proxy references objects in the Server process that are not COM objects, just simple C++ classes. These C++ classes can be destroyed and referenced from the proxy on a different thread.

I would like to first prevent further communication between client and server, then wait until ongoing communication is finished, then perform shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which langage has been used to implement your COM client/server.

But as far as I understand, it looks like you are facing a COM multithreading issue. What is the threading model of your COM server? (I suppose it multithreaded)

If it's the case, you should synchronize your threads.

The over way would be to transform the threading model of your COM server into a single threaded model. In that case, server shutting down call will be executed after previous client call finishes.

Answer (score 0):

- I suspect you really want [CoAddRefServerProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687190(v=vs.85).aspx) inside your C++ object's constructor (and [CoReleaseServerProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691324(v=vs.85).aspx) in the destructor).
  This will keep your server alive until the C++ objects go away.
  However, this won't prevent the client from requesting new instances, so you may also want:
- [CoRevokeClassObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688650(v=vs.85).aspx) to prevent new instances of the client from obtaining proxies.
- If you're feeling *really* nasty, [CoDisconnectObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680756(v=vs.85).aspx) will forcibly disconnect the proxy from the server.
  *